# Over-payment by ex-employer into 401k

Tags: united-states, 401k

I left my old employer on 3/10/2014, however, I left my 401k there.  Today I  received an email indicating that they over-paid into my account $500 and that i need to identify which funds I want to liquidate in order to pay them back.  While i certainly have no problem giving them the money back, what do i need to do to protect myself?  I plan on rolling that old 401K over to my new employer in August of this year.  They said I have to make a decision by Wednesday (gave me 48 hours).  Can they even do that?  Can they take the $ out without my giving written permission?

Comment: They can only take back unvested moneys. What does it mean "over-paid"? Who sent you the letter? Doesn't sound right to me.

Comment: My office mananger.  She said they "over-funded" my account by $496.  Here is a quote from her letter "Be advised that under our 401K Plan, you, as a participant, are unable to liquidate any monies in your account.  The Trustees of the LCM 401K Plan must handle this for you.  As a participant, you can only change your investments in the plan but cannot liquidate unless done by the Trustees of the Plan.  

SO, unless you designate the fund or funds in which you wish us to liquidate the $496.49, we will take an equal amount out of each of your four funds".

Comment: Like I said, I have no problem returning the money once i confirm it is owed to them, I just want to make sure I protect myself by requesting whatever it is I may need to protect myself.  They deposited that money in 1/2014, I left in 3/2014.  Not sure if that matters.  I also plan on rollong this over to my new employer next month.

Comment: I also do not understand why i have 2 days to decide.  Why 7/15/15?

Comment: did they explain the term over funded? was in non-vested matching funds? was it due to them pulling money in excess of the match amount? was it something else?

Comment: they did not.  They sent me some print-out that made zero sense (but that could be my fault)

Comment: @Wendy I suggest you asking them to provide explanation, and in writing, not in email. Make sure you understand the explanation and agree to it. There's also no reason for the 2 days time limit, and I believe if they take vested funds form your account without your authorization that would be theft. But talk to a lawyer.

Comment: Thank you both so much for your help, I really appreciate it!!

Comment: they did not explain, they just sent me an email saying they over-paid and asked that I sign a Distribution Request Form.  They also sent me a one page print-out that I could not make any sense out of.

Comment: "what do i need to do to protect myself?" Protect yourself against what?

Comment: When I left a former employer, the HR benefits coordinator was able to remove the un-vested employee match on her own time with no action required from me; it was removed in the same proportions as my final contribution selections.  Is this a similar case, except your ex-employer is offering you the courtesy of choosing a different set of ratios?  While my HR coordinator took a few months to remove the unvested amount, she did not take over a year.  The 2014 date in the post strikes me as odd.

Comment: @littleadv It's no more theft than if they reverse a direct deposit for too much money.  Just because they made an error and overpaid you does not mean you are entitled to the money.

Comment: @Eric and the OP is just supposed to believe them?

Comment: @littleadv No, of course not.  But calling it theft without knowing the situation is a bit much.  Imagine if they had deposited money beyond the participant's legal contribution limit or made some other administrative error?

Comment: @Eric that would be the OP's problem, not theirs. They have no inherent right to take back money that's vested, if the OP is not entitled to it - they must show it and the OP must repay. Similarly, you reversing an ACH without explanation may trigger a legal/criminal action against you.

Answer (score 1):

You definitely need more information. This could be a number of things. First of all I don't understand the reason for the 48 hours. I would definitely ask them to clarify why this is the case. Why are they noticing this a year later?

You are indeed a participant in the company 401k. the plan is theirs, and you are agreeing to play by their rules when you enroll. I would call HR and get more info.

This could be excess contribution or a "bank error in your favor" that they have found. It sounds like they over matched your 401k sense they want the money back.

Comment: OP is long gone. You are right, she should have insisted on more details.